# Operate on item by index in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Suppose I have a lists of lists (called someListofLists) and I want to multiply the 4th element of each sublist by 2.  I could do the following:

```
new=[]
for k in someListofLists:
    this=k
    this[3]=this[3]*2
    new.append(this)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this with list comprehensions or other techniques?   I would like the output to still be a list of lists.

Comment: `map(lambda l: l[0:3]+[l[3]*2]+l[4:], someListofLists)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension and `enumerate` to get the index and multiply by 2 if index == 3

```
>>> someListofLists = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
>>> [[e*2 if i==3 else e for i,e in enumerate(l)] for l in someListofLists]
[[1, 2, 3, 8, 5], [6, 7, 8, 18, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
def by_4(lst):
    r = lst[:]
    r[3] *= 2
    return r

someListofLists = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
new = [by_4(k) for k in someListofLists]
print(new)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 3, 8], [5, 6, 7, 16]]
```

Comment: I would like the output to still be a list of lists.

Comment: wrong, `new` in the OP contains full original lists, with the forth elements doubled.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, you can do this in-place with NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])

A[:, 3] *= 2

array([[ 1,  2,  3,  8],
       [ 5,  6,  7, 16]])
```

If you need a list, you can use `A.tolist()`, though often this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

`new = [e*2 if i == 3 else e for k in someListofLists for i,e in enumerate(k)]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` and slices:

```
>>> someListofLists=[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
>>> map(lambda l: l[0:3]+[l[3]*2]+l[4:], someListofLists)
[[1, 2, 3, 8, 5], [6, 7, 8, 18, 10]]
```

You can also combine `map`, `enumerate` and a  dict to apply various functions by index:

```
funcs={3: lambda x: x*2,
       4: lambda x: -x}

map(lambda sl: [funcs.get(i, lambda x: x)(e) for i,e in enumerate(sl)], someListofLists)

# [[1, 2, 3, 8, -5], [6, 7, 8, 18, -10]]
```